# How to get full test coverage with Jest and ReactJS, currently at 90.48% statements, 58.06% branch

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

With the simplest ReactJS component Jest is not reporting full test coverage. How to get statements and branch to show 100%.

Currently Jest shows `90.48% statements, 58.06% branch`.
Run with `jest --coverage`.

**MyThing.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyThing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Stuff
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**MyThing-test.js**

```
// __tests__/MyThing-test.js

jest.unmock('../app/views/static/MyThing');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

import MyThing from '../app/views/static/MyThing';


describe('MyThing', () => {

    const instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <MyThing />
    );          

  it('gets rendered', () => {    
    expect( TestUtils.isCompositeComponent(instance) ).toBeTruthy();        
  });


  it('is not DOM component', () => {   
   // checks if is a standard DOM element, i.e. <div>
    expect( TestUtils.isDOMComponent(instance) ).not.toEqual(true);    
  });

  it('isElementOfType is React element', () => {  
    expect( TestUtils.isElementOfType(<MyThing />, MyThing) ).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('render()', () => {    
    const retVal = instance.render();

    expect( retVal.type ).toEqual("div");       
  });

});
```

Comment: Dunno, maybe not every piece of code merits 100% coverage

Comment: @RobertMoskal I think you need to read my code example in a bit more detail. There's nothing in my class that should not be 100% covered by my Jest tests. I can only guess it's a bug with Jest, or Jest is also looking at code that isn't executed in the super class in `React.Component`.

Comment: expect(retVal.props.children.length).toEqual(1);

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the transpiled code from babel. See [issue #817](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/817) where this issue was worked on and just recently resolved.

This should be fixed with the upgrade to `jest@15`.

Though some people mentioned the need to add sourcemaps to their `.babelrc` such as:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "sourceMaps": "both"
    }
  }
}
```

and update their jest to explicitly with `"coverageCollector": "jest-babel-istanbul"`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. when you have a link in your answer, it is probable that the page get removed and your answer get useless for other people in the future